# How do we show $f$ is not increasing on any open interval containing $0$ in the following case?

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

Let $f(x)=x^2\sin(\frac1x)+\frac{x}{2}$ for $x\ne 0$ and $f(0)=0$.

How do we show  $f$ is not increasing on any open interval containing $0$?

My procedure:

We know $f'(x)=2x\sin (\frac1x)-\cos (\frac1x)+\frac12$

Maybe pick a sequence like $x_n=\frac{1}{2\pi n}$, then $f'(x_n)=-1+\frac12=-\frac12$. However, the issue is how do we prove such sequence/points exists in every open interval containing $0$?

Comment: You know that $\{x_n\}$ converges to $0$ right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**hint**

With your sequence $x_n=\frac {1}{2\pi n} $, we have

$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}x_n=0$$
thus $$\forall \epsilon>0 \;\; \exists N\in\mathbb N\;\;:$$

$$n>N\implies x_n\in (0-\epsilon,0+\epsilon) $$

> or

Let $b$ real $>0$ and $k$ integer $>0.$
take
$$n_k=\lfloor \frac {1}{2\pi b} \rfloor +k $$

then
$$n_k>\frac {1}{2\pi b} $$
and
$$0 <\frac {1}{2\pi n_k}<b $$